# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygimli'

Tags: python

I'm having trouble importing pyGIMLI on Jupyter Notebook. I installed it as recommended on https://www.pygimli.org/installation.html by creating a new environment and the installation went smoothly. However when I try to import it on Jupyter Notebook it cannot load it and I get : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygimli'". I launch Jupyter using the terminal after typing the command :

```
conda activate pg
```

so I believe it should work (I do the same for Obspy and it works like a charm!).

I found a test command to see if the installation went correctly :

```
python -c "import pygimli; pygimli.test(show=False, onlydoctests=True)"
```

I get 2 failures according to the command, however I don't really get what's causing trouble, nor do I get how to solve the problem. Here are two screenshots of the failures I get on the terminal :

[First screenshot of the failures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cye5P.png)

[Second screenshot of the failures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeJnE.png)

Comment: your screenshots tells the problem is something else

Comment: once I installed a package and I couldn't import it in Jupiter. I restarted my pc and it worked. you may test this costless action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what the problem was : I forgot to install ipykernel in the new environment. I could solve my issue using :

```
conda install nb_conda
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name mykernel
```

Sorry for my dumb issue and thank you to those who already commented my quesiton!